# Hello everyone, I want to find this specific font that I saw in the tv-series

Tags: fonts

I have one question that is not so much related to programming, but I believe that people in this community will be able to help me with it. I was watching a TV series and I saw this typewriter font and I really want to find that specific one if anyone can help me.

This is some screenshots of font :
[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screenshots are from a real typewriter then there is no specific font obviously.

However, you can use some kind of a typewriter font. There are many fonts that mimic old typewriters. For instance GNU Typewriter.

https://fontsarena.com/blog/free-vintage-typewriter-fonts/

Comment: It is not gnu because in the letter W is the central line to the end of the length at GNU and this one from the screenshot goes half length. Thanks anyway for your reply